# how to call java from a bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a bat file

with has

```
@call java -Xms1512m ....
```

java in this case is java 8, Instead of java, i want to point to java 9 location which is c:/java_9/jre/bin/java.exe

I tried

```
 @call c:/java_9/jre/bin/java.exe -Xms1512m ....
```

but this did not work.

Comment: So, define `JAVA_HOME` to point to  `c:/java 9/jre/` prior to calling java in your bat file

Comment: thanks. but is there any other way instead of setting javA_HOME?

Comment: If your path contains blank characters you should qoute the full path with double quotes : call "c:/java 9/jre/bin/java.exe"

Comment: Just try to put `c:/java 9/jre/bin/java.exe` in quotes or rename `java 9` to something like `java_9`. Btw, it is good to have error message in your question for clarity what doesn't work

Comment: try both , and also changed directory name from java 9 to java_9

Comment: Why are you using `Call`? If you have to prepend `java.exe`, _instead of just using `@C:\java_9\jre\bin\java.exe -Xms1512m …`_, why not use `Start`, e.g. Either `@Start C:\java_9\jre\bin\java.exe -Xms1512m …`, `@Start "" "C:\java 9\jre\bin\java.exe" -Xms1512m …` or `@Start /D C:\java_9\jre\bin java.exe -Xms1512m …`. _(the `/D` option sets the working directory for the command)_. _Note that the examples above use the Windows standard path separators **`\ `** instead of **`/`**_.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set JAVA_HOME properly then use the following script

```
@ECHO OFF

SET JAVA_CMD="%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java.exe

SET _CLASSPATH=<classpath_location>

SET JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m

%JAVA_CMD% %JAVA_OPTS% -classpath %_CLASSPATH% com.learn.Mainclass %*
```

Where the MainClass is the class that contains the main function. %* is used to pass parameter to main function.